# Why name of module not accessible when importing through 'from'

Tags: python, python-import

I observed that even if you import modules in python through `from` 
e.g

```
from b import x
```

whole module is loaded. It can be seen in `sys.modules` dictionary. So why the name of the module `b` is not accessible to our program. What am i missing?

It looks like namespace of the main(top-level) file does not have module name.

But I can not verify this as I am not able to see main file namespace. It also does not feel ok, just to remove one entry from `__dict__` without many advantages. Can somebody clear this in detail?

Comment: Why *would* it be accessible? By using `from b import x` you specified that you *only* wanted `x` to be added to the current namespace. If you want all of `b`, add `import b`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand that if i use `import b` I would get access to b, but I was looking for some reasons to why is it not logical to keep the module name accessible(in python) even if we want to use direct attributes of the module? What will be the overhead of this on execution?

Comment: Well *explicit is better than implicit*, for one. For another, that's what the reference says it does: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement. It's not that it doesn't *"keep the module name accessible"*, it doesn't make it accessible to begin with.

Comment: You get what you ask for. If you just want the `x` name in your namespace do `from b import x`. If you want the `b` name do `import b`. Why is that a problem? IMHO, it would be _bad_ design if the `from` import also dumped the module name into the namespace. It would make code messy to have a mixture of some objects from the module having simple names like `b` but others having qualified names like `x.a` and `x.c`.

Comment: I strongly agree with you both. But somewhere I still feel there is something more and I wish if I can get a perspective from python language developer's side on this.

Comment: What do you mean *"something more"*? Your question currently doesn't make sense. *"It also does not feel ok, just to remove one entry from `__dict__` without many advantages"* - your feelings aside, that isn't what happens. If you want to know about the implementation, it's open source: https://github.com/python/cpython

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what that syntax does; it only imports the names you specify, not the containing module. If you want the module itself, just do `import b`.

Comment: I understand that if i use import b I would get access to b, but I was looking for some reasons to why is it not logical to keep the module name accessible(in python) even if we want to use direct attributes of the module? What will be the overhead of this on execution?